# Resource on Infinite Systems of Difference Equations

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, self-learning, recurrence-relations

In my efforts (somewhere on the boundary of discrete mathematics and theoretical computer science), I have come upon the necessity of solving (or at least finding out some of the solution's properties) infinite systems of difference (NOT differential) equations (linear, autonomous, first-order). Solving countable systems is sufficient for my purpose.

However, I have almost no idea about how to solve such systems (and what are the solvability conditions). I have a feeling that a possible approach is to seek generalizations of the finite-dimensional method to infinite-dimensional spaces via the spectral theory of linear operators, but I have no idea about the details.

So my question is whether there are any resources that deal systematically with infinite systems of difference equations. I would be grateful either for a resource that can be read also without a knowledge of advanced mathematics (that is something readable for non-mathematicians) or, alternatively, for a more advanced resource with a recommendation where to learn the prerequisities. My mathematical background is unfortunately quite basic (I am a computer science major): possibly relevant fields I have a background in are calculus, linear algebra, some fundamentals of modern analysis, difference/differential equations, and basics of functional analysis (however I have very poor knowledge of spectral theory).

I would appreciate any resources dealing with this issue, as well as any recommendations about which parts of mathematics I am supposed to learn (preferably with some recommended resources). I am willing to invest a considerable amount of time into the study, but I would like to follow some recommended path that leads to the goal. In the case that the theory of infinite systems of differential equations is similar, I would appreciate also resources dealing with them.

EDIT: an example of such system: 
$$x_{n+1} = A \cdot x_n,$$
where $x_n$ are in $\ell^{\infty}$, $x_0$ is given (for instance, let $x_0 = (1,0,1,0,1\ldots)$), and $A$ is a linear operator that can be viewed as an infinite matrix (for instance)
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\ 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & \ldots \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & \ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \end{array}\right).$$
I have not been very careful, if this particular system makes sense and is well-behaved, but the form of my systems should be clear. $A$ is always a bounded operator on $\ell^{\infty}$ that can be (if needed) viewed as an infinite matrix that is $k$-diagonal for some fixed (relative to the system) constant $k$. However, these are details. I am not asking for a detailed solution, but mainly for a resource that treats such (or similar) systems and that will enable me to work out the details by myself.

ONE MORE EDIT: The matrix from the above example is symmetric by mistake. My matrices are not symmetric nor Hermitian in general (the operator is not necessarily self-adjoint).

Comment: Can you give an example of such a system?  Even a toy system would help clarify the concepts a bit...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you for your comment, I have edited the question with an example.

Comment: Can you give an example of a problem that has motivated you to consider systems of this form?

Answer (score 1):

So generalistic your question is the answer can be only general, some major research and application fields are

- Z-transformation is used on such systems in the context of *time
  discrete control systems*. Hence you will find concepts within the
  field of **cybernetics**, **systems' theory** and **control therory**
  (input/output, impulse/response, filters).
- In systems' theory
  regarding **discrete systems** on arbitrary sets; see for instance
  [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~mtns/papers/17484_4.pdf)
- Particularly in systems' theory when some time-continuous
  systems which have *delay* properties, could be reformed in infinite
  difference systems as well.
- In **quantum mechanics** such as discrete
  Schrödinger equations with infinity of solutions see for instance
  [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4691v1.pdf)
- In **synergetics** for some spacial pattern formation the nonlinear version of infinite difference equations can be deducted by discretizing the spacial modes.

In general when *discrete systems* can be set up in terms of *infinite* number of state variables or modes, or *continuous systems* scattered in such *discrete systems*, then you will have areas where you can learn from for such equations.

It would be really far too wide to raise here references and more details; the list is really long but what may help you is to use google by highlighting explicitly the terms **solution of systems of "infinite difference equation"** (do use the quotes). Further the **bold** mark ups above will give you a focus on field of research where you can further dig into.